# Exchange Array and Reverse

Tags: javascript, reverse

input : [2,4,5] , ['a', 'b', 'c']
output: ['c', 'b', 'a'] , [5,4,2]

```
function exchangeWith(a,b){
    [a,b] = [b,a].forEach(e  => e = e.reverse() )
}
```

I get this error :undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: `output: ['c', 'b', 'a'] , [5,4,2]` How do you want that as output? Do you actually want an array of arrays to be returned, or what?

Comment: I want it to return as 2 different arrays (a,b)

Comment: If you return `(a, b)`, you're invoking the comma operator, which means only `b` will be returned. Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)

is due to:

```
[a,b] = [b,a].forEach(/* ... */)
```

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) always returns `undefined` and:

```
[a,b] = undefined
```

Will raise the error, since `undefined` is not iterable.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is based on asumtion that you are porviding different arrays one at a time not the array of array. Let me know if you'r input will be array of array, I'll change the solution based on that.

You can use `lodash` library for this.

> const updatedArray = _.reverse(array);

Here is the sample:

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
let array2 = ["c","d","a"];

const test = (array, index) => {
  document.getElementById("input" + index).innerHTML = array.join(", ");
  const updatedArray = _.reverse(array);
  document.getElementById("output" + index).innerHTML = updatedArray.join(", ");
};

test(array, 1);
test(array2, 2);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Input: <span id="input1"></span></p>
    <p>Output: <span id="output1"></span></p>
    <br/>
    <p>Input: <span id="input2"></span></p>
    <p>Output: <span id="output2"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```